# Update entire pList array - swift

Tags: ios, swift, plist

I can retrieve the data from the existing pList.

I then need to append an Object to the data that I have retrieved.
Delete the data inside the pList and save the new Data that I have created

```
class PracAddPartVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var filePath: String?
    var dataRetrieved: [[String: String]] = []
    var listOfValves = [ValveStruct]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self

        filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "RecentValve", ofType: "plist")
        dataRetrieved = NSArray(contentsOfFile: filePath!) as! [[String: String]]

        for eachDataItem in dataRetrieved {
            let singleResult = ValveStruct(pn: eachDataItem["pn"] ?? "", type: eachDataItem["type"] ?? "", material: eachDataItem["material"] ?? "", manufacturer: eachDataItem["manufacturer"] ?? "")

            listOfValves.append(singleResult)
            print(listOfValves)
        }
    }
```

When I press a button.
I would like to append the new entry into the array at position 0.

Then I will need to delete the existing data inside the pList and save the new data that I have created.

```
    @IBAction func addNewRecentValve(_ sender: Any) {

        let newToAdd = ValveStruct(pn: "AB245245", type: "Valve", material: "Steel", manufacturer: "Company")

        listOfValves.insert(newToAdd, at: 0)
     }
```

Is anyone able to help please?

Comment: Never use `NSArray(contentsOfFile:` in Swift. Use `PropertyListDecoder` to decode the data directly into the struct. And you cannot modify a file in the application bundle.

Comment: A plist is the wrong data structure for this task. You probably want a database, maybe even Core Data depending what your plans are. At the very least you need a file that you own, not a plist.

Comment: Perhaps CoreData is the way to go.

I created pList from an excel document of data which contains around 1000 Objects.  
As theUser types in specific information, the correct object is selected from pList.

What I am trying to do is create another pList that will contain the 20 most recent Objects found.
So the user can select this from a TableView.
So was thinking that I could populate a tableView from a pList called Recent.plist

To update I was thinking of retrieving the data then update the array and then save the new array into the Recent.plist